# How to convert function substrb from oracle to mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle

I'm converting from oracle database to mysql database. In oracle database using function `substrb` returns a portion of a string, beginning at a specified byte position, and a specified number of bytes long.

Example

```
select substrb(account_name,1,2) from account;
```

But I don't find `substrb` in mysql.
Everyone can help me convert it or write function in mysql to convert it.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try `substr()`.  It is probably sufficient for an account name.

Comment: i used it but it 's not same. example >select substr("Trần",1,4);  in mysql difference >select substrb("Trần",1,4) from dual; in oracle because "ầ" is 3 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [`bit_length()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_bit-length) to return the amount of bits in a given string. Divide the result by 8 and you have a byte.

Here's some code you can use, but you might have to build in some more checks for example for string length and so on, to make it bullet proof to use with any given string or invalid parameters or reading the string backwards with negative parameters and so on.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS substrb;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION substrb(p_string varchar(255), p_start tinyint, p_len tinyint)
RETURNS varchar(255)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
    DECLARE v_pos_start tinyint;
    DECLARE v_len tinyint;
    DECLARE v_bytesRead tinyint;


    SET v_pos_start = 0;
    SET v_bytesRead = 0;
    IF (p_start < 1) THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSEIF (p_start = 1) THEN
        SET v_pos_start := 1;
    ELSE #p_start > 1 
        WHILE (v_bytesRead < p_start)
        DO
            SET v_bytesRead := v_bytesRead + (BIT_LENGTH(SUBSTR(p_string, 1 + v_pos_start, 1)) / 8);
            SET v_pos_start := v_pos_start + 1;
        END WHILE;
    END IF;

    SET v_len = 0;
    SET v_bytesRead = 0;
    IF (p_len < 1) THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSEIF (p_len = 1) THEN
        SET v_len := 1;
    ELSE #p_start > 1 
        WHILE (v_bytesRead < p_len)
        DO
            SET v_bytesRead := v_bytesRead + (BIT_LENGTH(SUBSTR(p_string, v_pos_start + v_len, 1)) / 8);
            SET v_len := v_len + 1;
        END WHILE;
    END IF;

    RETURN SUBSTR(p_string, v_pos_start, v_len);

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Example usage:

```
mysql(playground) > select substrb('a x test', 1, 7);
+---------------------------+
| substrb('a x test', 1, 7) |
+---------------------------+
| a x tes                   |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql(playground) > select substrb('a ü test', 1, 7);
+----------------------------+
| substrb('a ü test', 1, 7)  |
+----------------------------+
| a ü te                     |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql(playground) > select bit_length('ü');
+------------------+
| bit_length('ü')  |
+------------------+
|               16 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

`ü` is 2 bytes, therefore the result is one character shorter.

Or, with your example from the comments:

```
mysql(playground) > select substr("Trần",1,4);
+----------------------+
| substr("Trần",1,4)   |
+----------------------+
| Trần                 |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql(playground) > select substrb("Trần",1,4);
+-----------------------+
| substrb("Trần",1,4)   |
+-----------------------+
| Trầ                   |
+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks your help. But this function has problem.In oracle database, when i excute query >select substrb('Trần',1,4) from dual; It return result 'Tr' because oralce define 'ầ' is 3 byte,'â' is 2 byte. If you want to get value 'Trầ', you must query >select substrb('Trần',1,5) from dual; Please fix the function help me.

Comment: @KennyTran Had another look at it. This is related to the character set difference in Oracle and MySQL. It has nothing to do with the code. In my previous comment I also talked about collations (if you've read it), which was a mistake on my side, I confused those two terms. Anyway, see if you can fix this with another character set, please. Read more about this topic [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html) for a start.